# plutter problem: My app name is not showing same in mobile deivce overview

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

### My mobile app name is CWC(Khushi) but in my mobile device overview section is showing flutter demo. I dont know why?

My mobile app name is CWC(Khushi) but in my mobile device overview section is showing flutter demo. I dont know why?
My mobile app name is CWC(Khushi) but in my mobile device overview section is showing flutter demo. I dont know why?

this is my pubspec.yaml file

```
name: cwc
description: We are a Community Owned & Community Driven Movement. Our Innovative Wellness Ecosystem is led by Doctors, Health Heroes, Support Groups, Health Entrepreneurs and Pros, Wellness Product cum Service Providers – powered by Tech Platform and App to Scale, Access Content and Engage.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_fonts: ^2.1.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.8
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  image_picker: ^0.8.3+2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.18
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.2
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.5
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.0.0
  sign_in_with_apple: ^3.3.0
  skeletons: ^0.0.3
  flutter_login_facebook: ^1.2.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  country_calling_code_picker: ^2.0.0
  share: ^2.0.4
  flutter_inappwebview: ^5.3.2
  photo_view: ^0.13.0
  syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer: ^19.4.48-beta
  better_player: ^0.0.81
  audioplayers: ^0.18.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/app_icon.png"
  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

this is my menifest file

```
  <application
        android:label="Khushi (CWC)"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />

       <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
           android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

       <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
           android:configChanges=
               "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
           android:label="@string/app_name" />
       <activity
           android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
           android:exported="true">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
               <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

in my devide app name is showing cwc(khusi).
[image]

but here in my device overview is showing flutter demo name
[image]

Comment: Did you assign `CWC(Khushi)` to the title in `MaterialApp`? Sometimes you need use `flutter clean` after change application title in manifest , did you try that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `title` attribute in `MaterialApp` used as title of app in Recent apps section , so you should assign the specific name that you want.

Please check below sample :

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'CWC(Khushi)',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Hello App Home Page'),
        ),
        body: Hello(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```